# Trying to save a file back to the Dropbox location from Visual Studio via HTTP

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dropbox, cdn

I have a public file called test.html located:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22627000/Landing%20Page%20Code/test.html

I can open this up in Visual Studio (File -> Open, paste the link and click Open).  But I am unable to save it once I make a change to it.  When I do that, I get an error:

[image]
[image]

How can I be able to open, read/write, and save the file?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to supply a URL as the local filename to save to, but presumably Visual Studio can't accept that, so you should supply a valid local file name (and navigate to the local Dropbox folder if that's where you want to save it).

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of @Greg, I'm on my company machine, and unfortunately there's a process to get Dropbox installed (for local syncing/etc.), so I was hoping this way would work...